# Parsing NAL units using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I am new to MPEG-4 and taking baby steps to learn it. I am using FFMPEG as reference.

1. I understand that all mpeg-4 are encoded into NAL units and wrt to FFMPEG av_read_frame() function returns one NAL unit, Am I right? Is frame a NAL unit? (though it can be a combination of multiple NALs)
2. I also saw that h264_parser.c implements a function called h264_parse which is calling parse_nal_units() inside, If i need to get NAL units how can I use this parse_nal_units from my main function?
3. What is av_parse_Parse2() function do? does it return decoded NAL units?
4. OR  FFMPEG has -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb switch to dump raw NAL units, Can somebody help me understand how I can use the same from my main function?

Please help me out here...
-ash5

Answer (score 4):

For question 1:
The following article has links that will help you understand what NALs are.

[In h264 NAL units means frame.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858991/in-h264-nal-units-means-frame)

NALs are divided into several types, and depending on the type can contain decoding parameters (SPS, PPS), enhancement information (SEI) and video samples (slice header and data).  A common sequence from a broadcast transport stream would be SPS, PPS, SEI, slice_header(), slice_data(), SEI, slice_header(), slice_data() *

You probably don't need to understand ISO 14496-10 section 7.3 "Syntax in tabular form" for your application.

Comment: thanks Bob, I had seen that SO link, Have you used FFMPEG or any other library to decode individual NAL units and merge them to get one frame of picture??

Comment: I have not.  Most of my video manipulation has been at the container level.