# In h264 NAL units means frame.?

Tags: video, media-player, containers, h.264, video-codecs

I am working on a h264 video codec. I want to know: Is a single NAL unit in H264 equivalent to one video frame?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, a **sequence** of NAL units can be decoded into video frames, but they are not equivalent.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Abstraction_Layer#NAL_Units_in_Byte-Stream_Format_Use

http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=H.264

Comment: No problem, hope those links are helpful to you.